# Hidden code in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I downloaded some code earlier from a tutorial and I need to look it over so as I can see where I am going wrong, yet I am struggling with it. In theory, it should have rather a lot of code, 100 lines or so at least, but when I open it I get:

```
import TBG07a; 
var mygame:TBG07a = new TBG07a(this);
```

and I'm unsure why. I checked the Actionscript (3.0) properties, nothing hidden, I checked everything I can think of but it's 1 frame, 1 scene, 1 layer.... I can't think where any of the rest of the code would appear. It is of course a .fla file and it works completely when I run it.

I'm probab;y missing something stupid here but I'm unsure, can anybody help at all?

Ta.
John.

Comment: looks like obfuscated code.  what's the link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

John, check out the directory where *.fla file is located, if there are any .as files in that folder? If no files found, then check fla's Library pannel, if any movieclips there have "AS Linkage" property filled (if so, try editing those movieclips). Also you may check out "File"->"ActionScript Settings"->"Source Path" list (by default it consists only one "." folder).